# How to pass karate.prevRequest and response are the arguments from one feature file to another feature file

Tags: karate

I wanted to pass karate.prevRequest and response are the arguments to another feature

```
Background:
* def KLog = Java.type('com.support.KaratePrint')

@SmokeTest
Scenario: Fetch random quote

* print 'My method executed' +KLog.scenarioInfo('Scenario_1', tcDetails.Scenario_1)
Given path '/api/users/'+pageNo.Pageno
When method GET
Then status 200
```

Here I wanted to pass KLog, Karate.prevRequest and response are the arguments to another feature

Comment: Am keep on getting errors and saying null pointer exception. Please help me here

Comment: If you are getting errors, please add them to the question, and then delete any such remarks from comments. In other words, please put everything that readers need to see in the question itself

Comment: I am not familiar with Karate, so I may have misunderstood what in the above is code and what was intended to be Markdown formatting. Feel free to edit further so the question is presented in the most readable fashion.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is 
https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files

The example file is
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callfeature/call-feature.feature

Please see the other files in the directory
https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callfeature